# How can I keep a file in memory between runs of the rust binary?

Tags: file, memory, rust, io

When developing and testing I have a very large file that needs to be loaded into memory. This takes about 20 seconds each time I run the program.

Is there a way to keep the file in memory so that it doesn't need to be loaded each time?

Comment: Just spouting ideas, you can keep it in *shared memory* via another program and access it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "loaded".

If you're referring to transferring the data from storage to ram that's more or less what your operating system's IO cache already should be doing, assuming you have enough spare memory and you're not using methods that bypass that cache.

On linux it's called page cache and you can check whether a file is in the cache via `fincore`. Or you can simulate the cache being cold via `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` which will drop its contents (requires root).

If you mean moving the bytes from the OS's cache into your application then that shouldn't take much time as long as you use sufficiently large block sizes for the read calls or use mmap. The latter is a dual-edged sword, used incorrectly it can actually cause slowdowns.

If you mean decoding the bytes into some application-specific logic then that's not IO but deserialization.

Comment: On "[mmap] is a dual-edged sword, used incorrectly it can actually cause slowdowns": Assuming the file fits in memory (OP implies it will), `mmap` + `posix_madvise` with flag `POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED` typically removes such issues by telling the OS you'll need to process the whole file, so it (typically, not guaranteed by the spec since this is just advice) proactively populates pages in bulk, rather than populating on demand in response to page faults. Other advice can be used for "too large for memory files" depending on how they're used (e.g. `SEQUENTIAL` when it's all read once and discarded).

Comment: @ShadowRanger No matter how optimized it might be, `mmap()` will always involve the creation of physical-to-virtual mappings that can be both expensive and a serious performance bottleneck.  If those mappings only get used once, or they have to be remapped because they get paged or swapped out because of memory pressure, that will likely cause `mmap()` to be slower than simply using `read()`.  Reading a file just once and then discarding it is the worst possible use case for `mmap()`.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping to correctly identify the bottleneck. In this case it looks like the deserialization is actually what's slowing everything down. Do you have any tips on how i can mitigate that? Where can i save the deserialized data so that it gets cached between runs?

Comment: That probably should be a new question since there are many ways to do deserialization